# C# API Testing Error: "AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

My https get method for a specific id is working just fine however the get that's meant to return a list isn't. I don't understand how this could be a mapper problem if it works for the method that takes an id?

Controller methods:

```
 // GET: api/Hotels
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<HotelDto>>> GetHotels()
    {
        var hotels = _hotelsRepository.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<HotelDto>>(hotels));
    }

    // GET: api/Hotels/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<HotelDto>> GetHotel(int id)
    {
        var hotel = await _hotelsRepository.GetAsync(id);

        if (hotel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<HotelDto>(hotel));
    }
```

Automapper:

```
 public MapperConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<Country, CreateCountryDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Country, GetCountriesDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Country, GetCountryDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Country, UpdateCountryDto>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Hotel, HotelDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Hotel, CreateHotelDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
```

Detailed error response

````
Mapping types:
AsyncStateMachineBox`1 -> List`1
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[HotelListing.API.Data.Hotel, HotelListing.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[HotelListing.API.Repository.GenericRepository`1+<GetAllAsync>d__4[[HotelListing.API.Data.Hotel, HotelListing.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], HotelListing.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[HotelListing.API.Models.Hotels.HotelDto, HotelListing.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]```
````

Comment: Can you share your Hotel.cs and HotelDto.cs classes, looks like there is a property or name mismatch in the DTO.

Comment: @AjayManagaon there is no need. According to OP `GetHotel(int id)` is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `await` the result of `GetAllAsync` so you are trying to map the returned `Task<List<Hotel>>` instead of the desired `List<Hotel>` (more precisely `Task`'s inheritor - [`AsyncStateMachineBox`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ce689d9189d549e249f4bb5e3d9aeef322464bfb/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs#L273)). Try:

```cs
var hotels = await _hotelsRepository.GetAllAsync();
return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<HotelDto>>(hotels));
```

Comment: Of course, very silly of me. Apologies & thank you